# SQL Database Design Feedback for Home Business

Tags: database, database-design

I am developing a database for my wife's business so she can track her Cost of Goods and although I am familiar with SQL I not had to design a database in many years so I am looking for some design feedback. My structure is as follows:

**Tables**

***Suppliers***

This is who we buy the product from.

***Events***

One supplier can have many events (estate sale, etc). The Foreign Key Events.SupplierID points to the Primary key in the suppliers table.

***Products***

One Event can have many products. Each product is unique. The FK products.EventID points to the PK Events.ID.

***SalesRecords***

Each product can only be sold once since each product is unique. This table keeps all of the information about the sale, related fees, etc so we can calculate profit. A record is only generated here when a product is sold. The FK SalesRecords.ProductID points to the PK Products.ID.

Comment: What is database size your are trageting in next 4-5 years? As per that you need to define your database sturcture.

Comment: We usually have around 2K products at all times and sell around 100 - 150 a month. My goal is to use this database to run metrics on how well we did at previous sales, what is currently in the inventory, etc...